# "See also" in index entries

Tags: cross-referencing, indexing

LaTeX's indexing packages `makeindex` and `xindy` provide good support for the basic features of an index: runs of pages, nested index sub-entries, and cross-references of the form:

> Yurmurm-Peffifoss, Rudwooll, *see* Peffifoss, Rudwooll Y.

Well and good. However, my indexer also demands an additional type of index entry, the "see also". A see-also entry combines page references and cross-references into a single item:

> Peffifoss, Rudwooll Y., 58–59, 65; *see also* "The Preoccupation of Mr. Peffifoss"; Thurber, James, nightmarish bureaucratic fantasies of

Is there a ready-made command for such an entry?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`makeidx` package provides the command `\seealso`, which does exactly this and has the same syntax as `\see`